# C# What is doing this constructor if the attribute is not part of the class?

Tags: c#, constructor, blazor

I had this line of code

```
public SchedulerCust Scheduler;
```

`SchedulerCust` is a custom class I wrote.
Visual Studio gave me the option to refactor the before mentioned code to this:

```
public Car(SchedulerCust scheduler)
{
    Scheduler = scheduler;
}
```

I don't know if this is a constructor. The problem is that Scheduler is not part of the Car class. I'm working with Blazor, I don't know if that has anything to do with this. Can somebody help me understand what the difference between the lines of code is?

Thanks in advance!

PD: Sorry for my bad English :/

I tried to search for a solution on the internet but I can't find anything.

Comment: That is a constructor, yes.  It's specifically a constructor for the `Car` class and accepts a parameter of type `SchedulerCust`.  This constructor, by itself, is inherently neither right nor wrong.  It entirely depends on what you want.  It's not really clear to me what you're really trying to ask other than "is this a constructor", to which the answer is "yes".

Comment: VS is suggesting constructor injection to support [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection).  You probably want to skip that for now. But do note that having a _public_ field is considered a bad practice.

Comment: @HH what should i? Is it better to declare it as a propertie?

Comment: Yes, add `{get; set; }`

Comment: Actually if it's being initialised in the constructor and it will never be changed afterwards you should only add `public SchedulerCust  Scheduler { get; }` (i.e. omit the `set`)

Comment: I would have thought that if VS is offering to add the ctor, it would also add the property for you at the same time.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - not when it's already there (or a field as in this case).